# Type hinting for expression of type "Float | ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]"

Tags: python, types

I'm creating a simple wrapper class for scikit-learn function `median_absolute_error`.

```
from sklearn.metrics import median_absolute_error
    class MedAbsError:
        name:str = "MAE"
        def compute(self, predictions: np.ndarray, observations: np.ndarray) -> float | np.ndarray:
            return median_absolute_error(y_pred=predictions, y_true=observations)
```

However, Pylance is reporting:

> Expression of type "Float | ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]" cannot be
> assigned to return type "float | ndarray[Unknown,
> Unknown]"

Why is that? I've searched for Float in numpy datatypes, but I didn't find it in that section.

Comment: have you tried `from typing import Float`?

Comment: Yes... There's no Float in typing... @LucasM.Uriarte